# How to get only numbers from a string

Tags: json

I have some code in json to get data from domoticz.

```
local Data = parsedJson["result"][1]["Data"]

print("Data:", Data)
```

The outcome;
2.700 kWh

How to get rid of the kWh ?
So the outcome will be 2.700

Answer (score 0):

You can write a regular expression which accepts **numbers** and **.** only. 
Not sure but you could try to cast the variable to float and it will preserve only the number with floating point